# How to append data from one table to another upon the deletion of data from the first table

Tags: ms-access

I have a sales entry form named frmSales. I also have on this frmSales a continuous form called tblSalesMAIN subform2, which has the same datasource as frmSales. I seek to have entries made into the datasource of both frmSales and tblSalesMAIN subform2 which is tblSalesMAIN, have all of it's current data appended to a separate table called tblSalesMAIN1. After which all of the content of tblSalesMAIN be deleted to make room for a fresh entry.
Below is how I have tried to go about it without success. the commented code is what I can not figure out. 
Thanks for your assistance

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
 'Dim dbs As DAO.Database
 'set dbs = Current.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tblSalesMAIN]")
 'dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tblSalesMAIN1 " _
 '& "SELECT * "
 '& "FROM [tblSalesMAIN];"
 'dbs.Close


 'INSERT INTO tblSalesMAIN1 [(salesID[, salesTime[, salesDate[, unitPrice[, quantity[, cashTendered[, change[, price]]]]]]])] SELECT ([tblSalesMAIN.SalesID[, tblSalesMAIN.salesTime[, tblSalesMAIN.salesDate[, tblSalesMAIN.unitPrice[, tblSalesMAIN.quantity[, tblSalesMAIN.cashTendered[, tblSalesMAIN.change[, tblSalesMAIN.price]]]]]]])

 'DoCmd.RunQuery 


 If MsgBox("You are about to delete all records. Are you sure?", _
 vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNO Then
 Exit Sub
 End If
 strSQL = "DELETE*FROM tblSalesMAIN subform2"
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 DoCmd.RunSQL
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 Me.Requery
 Me.Refresh

 End Sub


 Private Sub cmdd_Click()
 DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
 Me.Refresh

 End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: I have to ask why you want to do this, normally deleting records is a very rare task. You would normally simply flag them as completed / archived with a date flag and subsequently filter them out in future operations.

Generally moving or copying data between tables is a sign of a poorly thought out design

Comment: i intend to keep the appended data in tblSalesMAIN1 to build an individual transaction report. But the table of which data is deleted from, is only there to show to the cashier a listed items in a particular sales transaction he/she is submitting, after which the list is to be cleared to make way for a new sales entry list.

Comment: I wouldn't mind to use any other methods, you guys may suggest, i.e if only the end goal meets with my desires

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you - Instead of creating the table, just query the data you need to display?